# Are there nontrivial natural number solutions for $\log_{n_1}(m_1) = \log_{n_2}(m_2)$ with $\gcd(n_1, m_1) = \gcd(n_2, m_2) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

Let $n_1, m_1, n_2, m_2 \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$ such that $\gcd(n_1, m_1) = \gcd(n_2, m_2) = 1$ and
$$
\log_{n_1}(m_1) = \log_{n_2}(m_2).
$$
Does it follow that $n_1 = n_2$ and $m_1 = m_2$?

**Equivalent formulation**

This is the original motivation.
 Let $n_1, m_1, n_2, m_2 \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$ such that $\gcd(n_1, m_1) = \gcd(n_2, m_2) = 1$. Can we always find $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
n_1^a m_1^b > 1 \\
n_2^a m_2^b < 1 ?
$$

Comment: Can be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3158160/293846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim does not follow. Consider:
$$
\log_4 9=\log_2 3.
$$

Comment: You are right, I asked the wrong question. I really should have asked about squarefree $n_1, n_2, m_1, m_2$, but I got greedy.

Comment: @Vincent With squarefree $n_1,n_2,m_1,m_2$ it should work.  Probably even much weaker  restriction that $\frac{m_1}{n_1}$ and $\frac{m_2}{n_2}$ are not powers of the *same* rational number would suffice.